# How to change each value of many classes with the same name

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page were there is some products, what I'm trying to do is to calculate the new quantity each time the user clicks the delete button, but I have so many products, and I'm using the same classe name, so i don't know how I can manipulate or change the value of quantity when the user clicks the specific button for each product

right now, when I click the delete ( supprimer ) button it apply for all the product, but I'm looking to change the value when I click on the specific button for each product ?

```js
const qte = document.querySelectorAll('.qte');
const suppr = document.querySelectorAll('.suppr');

suppr.forEach(function(button) {
  button.onclick = (event => {
    for (let i = 0; i < qte.length; i++) {
      qte[i].innerText = parseInt(qte[i].innerText) - 1;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../img/produit_newyork_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">New York City</p>
            <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">1</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right suppr">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../img/produit_londres_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Londres City</p>
            <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">3</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right suppr">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might need to consider using the `this` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative addressing. Use this.closest("container") or event.target.closest...

Two versions, one for each button

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.suppr').forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = (event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const qte = event.target.closest(".list-group-item").querySelector(".qte");
    let val = qte.innerText;
    val--;
    if (val >= 0) qte.innerText = val;
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../img/produit_newyork_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">New York City</p>
            <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">1</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right suppr">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../img/produit_londres_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Londres City</p>
            <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">3</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right suppr">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative is event handler on the container:

```js
document.querySelector(".card").addEventListener("click", event => {
  const tgt = event.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("suppr")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const qte = tgt.closest(".list-group-item").querySelector(".qte");
    let val = qte.innerText;
    val--;
    if (val >= 0) qte.innerText = val;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../img/produit_newyork_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">New York City</p>
            <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">1</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right suppr">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../img/produit_londres_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Londres City</p>
            <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">3</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right suppr">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I posted a new recommended version which is to add the event listener to the container